# Windows Phone 8.1 UserControl with canvas in a ScrollViewer doesn't work

Tags: canvas, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I have the following in a user control:

```
<Grid Background="#FFEEEEEE" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="TitleLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>

    <Border BorderBrush="#FFE2E2E2" Margin="10,60,20,80" CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid Background="#ffffffff">
            <Grid x:Name="SignatureGrid" Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sign here" Foreground="#FFEEEEEE" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="100"/>
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF333333" BorderThickness="1" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,20,50" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sign here" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="#FF333333" FontSize="14" Margin="20,0,0,27"/>
            </Grid>

            <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Background="Transparent" PointerPressed="inkCanvas_PointerPressed" PointerMoved="inkCanvas_PointerMoved" PointerReleased="inkCanvas_PointerReleased" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <Button x:Name="ClearButton" Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="162" Background="#FF46B2D5" BorderThickness="0,0,2,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

I then have a Page which contains the following:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" x:Name="QuestionsScroller" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="SectionContentPanel" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

In the Page code behind I dynamically add the control (and other controls) to the stackpanel. In it's current form, the canvas is not working but if I remove the ScrollViewer, the canvas works perfectly, but I obviously cannot scroll to the controls below it.

In my PointerMoved event I have:

```
Point currentPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(inkCanvas).Position;
if (_startPoint != currentPoint)
{
    _line.Points.Add(currentPoint);
    mHasDrawing = true;
}
```

With the ScrollViewer the startpoint and endpoint are never different (I guess because the canvas is moving with my finger/mouse as I drag across the screen/emulator. Without the ScrollView, as I said, it works as expected.

So the question is, how can I implement a Canvas within a scrollViewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing about with this for a while, I asked the question on StackOverflow, then within 10minutes I figured it out - Here's the answer for anyone who wants to do the same thing:

In your PointerPressed event you need to disable the scrollViewer Scroll Mode:

```
private void inkCanvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        //get to the scrollViewer
        StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)this.Parent;
        ScrollViewer sv = (ScrollViewer)sp.Parent;
        sv.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;

        //Rest of code.
    }
```

At this point the Canvas will work, but you still won't be able to scroll until you enable the ScrollViewer again. You can do this in the PointerReleased event:

```
private void inkCanvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //get to the scrollViewer
        StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)this.Parent;
        ScrollViewer sv = (ScrollViewer)sp.Parent;
        sv.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Auto;

        //Rest of code
    }
```